# Quickbooks Sale Event trigger PHP action (WebHooks, Triggers & Events)

Tags: php, quickbooks

How to make Quickbooks notify external server? In other words: On event "Sale" run script on URL:

> sample.com/newsale.php?product_id=1&hash=***********

Basically, I'm looking for Quickbooks events notifications to some urls.

Comment: I don't know what code you've written if any, but you should post more. Also, you may want to reconsider having the hash in the URL...

Comment: No code. I just need some documentation on Quickbooks events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks does not have anything like what you're asking for (webhooks).

What you're asking for does not exist.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for you reply. I was reviewing your system. :) Is this possible to create kind of complex and probably not most reasonable, but working sync system with PHP using your library? I want to build warehouse system which will interact with Quickbooks. I see it as: Mirroring of Quickbooks to MySQL, then sync sold items with entries in my warehouse system using cron for example.

Comment: Definitely possible, and no events needed. Look at the example MySQL mirror stuff we have in the docs - https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php   It does roughly what you're asking for. There are also some _import.php examples in the docs which might be helpful if you don't want to go the full MySQL mirror functionality.